# href alert returning undefined instead of the href value

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to get the href inside of my  to appear int he alert but it returns undefined the .contentUpdate class belongs to the parent div and i know that works because the "new HTML" appears upon click. However, in the alert before that event it returns underfined instead of the href for the link.

I've tried various solutions such as using the on() method instead of click but doesnt work either. I know its gotta be something simple, just cant figure it out and its bugging me. Thanks alot!

HTML

```
<li data-filtertext="" class="contentUpdate"><a href="#1-1" >Part 1</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="" class="contentUpdate"><a href="#1-2" >Part 2</a></li>
```

SCRIPT (JQUERY)

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
        /* Act on the event */
        //alert("asdfsas")
        alert($(this).attr("href");
        $("#mainContent").html("new HTML");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** `$(this)` is the `<li>` element which have no attribute `href`. The `href` belongs to `<a>` tag.

**Solution:**

`$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
        alert($(this).children().attr('href'));
        $("#mainContent").html("new HTML");
});`

Comment: Thanks so much man! Perfect. I shouldve known better than that. Thats exactly what it was. Thanks alot Jed!

Comment: Use `children().first().attr('href')` to make sure it works fine when you add more elements in the `<li>` tag.